# while trying to read a particular text from notepad am facing Run Error :- Object doesnt support this property or method

Tags: vba, qtp, hp-uft

```
set objFileToRead = CreatObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
Set strReadline=objFileToRead.OpenTextFile(strpath,1)     
Do While strReadline.AtEndofStream<>True  
strRecordName = Trim(Mid(strReadLine,52,15)
```

AT 4th LINE FACING ERROR in hp-UFT Run Error :- Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. We expect a minimal, reproducible example and as moch error output as possible. Please add the error output you get.

Comment: It would also be helpful when you describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: sorry i forgot to explain about that ....am just trying to read some particular text from   the notepad

Comment: Please paste your entire sub or function for us to help you. Pasting small code samples raise more questions than answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please paste the code without syntax error .Your code  should be like this

```
strpath="C:\Users\561320\Documents\Saikrishna\caffeine\readme.txt"
set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
Set strReadline=objFileToRead.OpenTextFile(strpath,1)     
Do While strReadline.AtEndofStream<>True  
strRecordName = Trim(Mid(strReadLine.Readline,52,15))
Wscript.echo strRecordName 
Loop
```